# Memory Error when Transcribing Audio Using Flask and whisper_timestamped Library

Tags: python, flask, paas

I'm encountering a memory-related issue while trying to transcribe audio files using Flask and the whisper_timestamped (https://github.com/linto-ai/whisper-timestamped) library. I've deployed my app on Render and I'm using a /transcribe endpoint to handle audio transcription requests. However, I'm consistently running into the following error:

```
[ERROR] Worker (pid:67) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
```

I've provided the relevant code snippet below:

```
# Flask app setup and imports

@app.route('/transcribe', methods=['POST'])
def transcribe():
    if 'audio' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No audio file provided.'}), 400

    audio_file = request.files['audio']

    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    temp_audio_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, "temp_audio.wav")
    audio_file.save(temp_audio_path)

    result = transcribe_audio(temp_audio_path)

    os.remove(temp_audio_path)
    os.rmdir(temp_dir)

    return jsonify(result), 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'm using the whisper_timestamped library to transcribe audio and obtain word timestamps. The error occurs when the worker process handling the request is terminated due to memory issues. I suspect that the library or model might be memory-intensive, causing the app to exceed its memory allocation.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this memory-related error? Are there any strategies or best practices I can follow to prevent my app from running out of memory during audio transcription?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me know when you find a solution. I am using a free version of the API as well and looks like I keep running into SIGKILL memory issue as well.

Comment: Update: I was able to resolve the SIGKILL memory issue by switching from Render.com to Google Cloud Functions and increasing the memory allocation by 1024. This change provided the necessary resources for smooth audio transcription without running into memory constraints. If you're experiencing similar memory issues, consider adjusting the deployment environment and memory settings. Hope this helps!